# Flurry not tracking specific event

Tags: android, flurry

I'm using Flurry for analytics in my Android app.  For the most part it works fine except for trying to record one event.  I have a ListView and when a user clicks on an item in the ListView, I'm recording the item name.  I don't know if it has something to do with trying to record the event right before a new Activity is launched or not.  If I debug my code the logging event and onStart/onStop are both hit.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
   super.onStart();

  FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "flurryId");
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();

   FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(final ListView l, final View v, final int position, final long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    FlurryAgent.logEvent("Item - viewed");

    final Intent browser = new Intent(this, Browser.class);

    this.startActivity(browser);
 }
```

Comment: I would be suprised if there was a race condition but to test I would put a second or two wait between the event and the activity start.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that Flurry does have a limit of 300 for events. If you exceed that limit, then additional events are not recorded. I only found out about this when I went to the Manage->Events section, and read the small texts at the top of the event list.